# adding psql path to profile, but didn't work

Tags: bash

I don't want to have to set my path everytime I start a terminal session, but I couldn't get this right. I updated all `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` to:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/bin:$PATH
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: What didn't work?  It is not clear what your issue is

Comment: after i restart the terminal, i couldn't find psql command if not setting path again.

Comment: What shell starts when you log into the terminal?  depending how your terminal is set up, it might not be sourcing any of those files when you log on.